# Generate a class for a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of DIVs each with an id of 'box'. I want to give each #box DIV a class of either:

= col1
= col2
= col3
= col4

So I need to give each DIV a class of any of the above, ideally distributed evenly (10 x col1, 10 x col2...etc.).

How can I generate the number, attach it to the class string and then assign one to each DIV?

Comment: I know that ids don't have to be unique, but why on earth wouldn't you make 'box' a class rather than an id attribute if it's being applied to multiple elements?

Comment: In html and related mark ups, an id should be used once (it is an identity). A class can be used as much as possible.

Comment: Well shoot me down in flames guys! Thanks you've taught me so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, your're meaning basic traversing through the DOM with jquery.

If so, this jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcmlxxxiii/4qxPX/) might help you.

```
$('div#box').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('col'+(i+1)); // `i` starts from 0 
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit i to be within a range of 1 to 5?

Comment: Sure. Just `return` from the function like this: `if (i > 4) return;` before `$(this).addClass('col'+(i+1));`